# Paypal : change the business name on Paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal

In this image I have to change my business name which is expected to display on top of "Your order summary"

[image: In this image I have to change my business name which is expected to display on top of "Your order summary"]

Anyone please provide me a solution ,Thanks in advance.....

After I loggin to sandbox account , Igot a screen as,

[image: screen after login]

Comment: In this image I have to change my business name which is expected to display on top of "Your order summary"

Comment: if you have paypal sandbox account then you can set it from there

Comment: yes I have , but I cant find where to set

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you talking about the Sandbox or the live site?  The procedures are going to be slightly different for each one.

For the Sandbox:

1. Go to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com and log in to the account.
2. Click **Profile**.  (Click on Profile -- don't choose any of the items in the pop-up menu.)
3. Click **Business Information**.  (It's in the **Account Information** column.)
4. Click **Change name**.  (It's next to the Business Contact Name.)
5. Click **Business Name Change (business name)**, then click **Continue**.
6. Enter the new business name in the **New business name** box, then click **Continue**.
7. You're done.

For the live site:

1. Go to https://www.paypal.com and log in to the account.
2. Under **Profile**, click **My Business Info**.
3. Next to **Name**, click **Change**.
4. Jump to number 5 in the procedure above.

Comment: Thanks Mat , I can find it by loggin to business test account and change it successfully.